# Google sheets script for hiding or deleting cell if it is empty?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am new to this so bear with me. I currently have a google sheet that has formulas in different cells. I want to be able to hide the empty cells if they are blank. Is there a way I can do that? For example, I want to be able to delete all empty cells between B11 and B20.

This is something I have found online but it is not quite doing what I want it to do:

```
 function adder() {
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('NY Quote');
     var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
     for (var i = 1; i < lastRow+1; i++) {

         //var valueB = sheet.getRange('B'+(lastRow-i+1)).getValue() + "";
         if((sheet.getRange('B'+(lastRow-i+1)).getValue())=="") {
             sheet.getRange('B'+(lastRowi+1)).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
         }
     }
 }
```

P.S. will the script work if the cells are merged?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script in your sample loops from `i = 1` to `i < lastRow+1` - that is from the first to the last row.

If you want the script to loop from row 11 to row 20 instead - change the loop condition to:

`for (var i = 11; i < 21; i++)`

Comment: Hi! just one more thing. What if I wasn't the same thing between B11:D11? I tried to write it as suchbut it made all the cells blank:     if((sheet.getRange('B'+'C'+'D'+(lastRow-i+1)).getValue())=="")
     {
       sheet.getRange('B'+'C'+'D'+(lastRow-i+1)).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
     }

Comment: If any of the cells between `B11:D11` is blank - do you want to delete the specific cell or the whole row?

Comment: If any of the cells between B11:D11 is blank - I would want to delete the whole row

Comment: In this case, you need to create a nested loop ot iterate not only through rows, but also through columns. Have a look a e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282187/find-position-of-a-cell-containing-a-specific-string/32289541#32289541) sample, I hope it is helpful for understanding!

Comment: I tried creating my nested loop but Unfortunately, I still get the same result. You've been of great help. I will keep on trying